How many arrangements are there of seven as, eight bs, three cs, and six ds with no occurrence of the consecutive pairs ca or cc?
Can someone please help me see the error with my inclusion/exclusion approach to this problem:
P: How many arrangements are there of seven a's, eight b's, three c's, and six d's with no occurrence of the consecutive pairs ca or cc?
My problematic approach is this:
Count the bad cases: Count # with ca or cc, then subtract instances with both ca and cc. Furthermore, I broke down the case with ca and cc into the subcases with two blocks 'cc' and 'ca' and one block 'cca'. This undercounts, so I add back the block 'ccca'.
$$\frac{24!}{7!\cdot8!\cdot3!\cdot6!}-\left(\frac{23!}{6!\cdot8!\cdot2!\cdot6!}+\frac{23!}{7!\cdot8!\cdot6!}-\frac{22!}{6!\cdot8!\cdot6!}\cdot2+\frac{21!}{6!\cdot8!\cdot6!}\right)$$
This yields a different value than my two other approaches:
My first other approach is to use a summation. There are two cases:
There is no c at the end position
There is a c at the end position
The first case equates to counting the number of ways to select positions for c out of the first 23 spots so that no two are adjacent. A ‘b’ or a ‘d’ must follow c. Let k be the number of b’s after all the c’s. There are nCr(3, k) ways to order the b’s and d’s following the c’s. Then order the remaining 18 elements:
$$\sum_{k=0}^{3}\operatorname{nCr}\left(23-2,\ 3\right)\cdot\operatorname{nCr}\left(3,\ k\right)\cdot\frac{18!}{7!\cdot\left(8-k\right)!\cdot\left(6-\left(3-k\right)\right)!}$$
The second case equates to counting the number of ways to select two positions for c out of the first 22 spots so that no two are adjacent. A ‘b’ or a ‘d’ must follow c. Let k be the number of b’s after all the c’s. There are nCr(2, k) ways to order the b’s and d’s following the c’s. Then order the remaining 19 elements:
$$\sum_{k=0}^{2}\operatorname{nCr}\left(22-1,\ 2\right)\cdot\operatorname{nCr}\left(2,\ k\right)\cdot\frac{19!}{7!\cdot\left(8-k\right)!\cdot\left(6-\left(2-k\right)\right)!}$$
The total is 1.588809222×10^11
My second other approach is this:
Arrange as, bs, and ds first:
_ a_b_b_a_a_b_a_b_b_a_b_d_d_d_a_d_d_b_b_a_d _
We have 22 places to insert c.
To avoid cc: Select 3 distinct places.
To avoid ca: Select places not before a
$$\frac{21!}{7!\cdot8!\cdot6!}\cdot\operatorname{nCr}\left(22-7,\ 3\right)$$
This total is also 1.588809222×10^11

Your "Finally, another solution online" looks attractive

You can have as many as three ca blocks in the arrangement.  Notice that you have two cc blocks if the sequence ccc appears in the arrangement and two cc blocks and one ca block if the sequence ccca appears in the arrangement.
